# What is the proper way to take the first order derivatives when creating a Christoffel symbol?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to follow the construction of a Christoffel symbol on this link [Einstein Relativity Easy](http://einsteinrelativelyeasy.com/index.php/general-relativity/29-christoffel-symbol-use-case-calculation-in-polar-coordinates).  Specifically, I'm trying to come up with a factory (simple, unambiguous steps) for generating the symbol rather than analyzing every step.
Halfway down the page, it's time to compute $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$.
$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{x}{r}=Cos(\theta)$$
It's obvious here that the author is making use of the formula:$$r(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$The problem I have is that there's another way to obtain $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$:
$$r(x,\theta)=\frac{x}{Cos(\theta)}$$$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=Sec(\theta)$$
Why is the first formula preferred over the second formula?

Comment: You can't use $r(x, \theta)$ since it mixes two separate coordinate systems as arguments.

Comment: So what happens if you have a coordinate system that doesn't resolve nicely from the first coordinate system?  If we didn't have that identity, then the second order derivative would have been in terms of $(r, \theta)$ and the first order derivative would have been in terms of $(x, y)$.  It seems like a convenient accident that the identities of $x, y$ resulted in a clean answer in terms of $\theta$.

Comment: Use `D[x/Cos[ArcTan[y/x]], x] // FullSimplify`, then we have out `1/Sqrt[1 + y^2/x^2]` = `x/r`=$\cos\theta $